# R: Avoid repeating lines of code using R subsets in scripts

Tags: r, loops, macros, subset

I'm very new to R - but have been developing SAS-programs (and VBA) for some years. Well, the thing is that I have 4 lines of R-code (scripts?) that I would like to repeat 44 times. Two times for each of 22 different train stations, indicating whether the train is in- or out-going. The four lines of code are:

```
dataGL_FLIin <- subset( dataGL_all, select = c(Tidsinterval, Dag, M.ned, Ugenr.,Kode, Ugedag, FLIin))
names(dataGL_FLIin)[names(dataGL_FLIin)=='FLIin'] <- 'GL_Antal'
dataGL_FLIin$DIR<-"IN"
dataGL_FLIin$STATION<-"FLI
```

To avoid repeating the 4 lines 44 times I need 2 "macro variables" (yes, I'm aware, that this is a SAS-thing only, sorry). One "macro variable" indicating the train station and one indicating the direction. In the example above the train station is **FLI** and the direction is **in**. Below  the same 4 lines are demonstrated for the train station **FBE**, this time in **out**-going direction.

```
dataGL_FBEout <- subset( dataGL_all, select = c(Tidsinterval, Dag, M.ned, Ugenr.,Kode, Ugedag, FBEout))
names(dataGL_FBEout)[names(dataGL_FBEout)=='FBEout'] <- 'GL_Antal'
dataGL_FBEout$DIR<-"OUT"
dataGL_FBEout$STATION<-"FBE"
```

I have looked many places and tried many combinations of R-functions and R-lists, but I can't make it work. Quite possible I'm getting it all wrong. I apologize in advance if the question is (too) stupid, but will however be very grateful for any help on the matter.

Pls. notice that I, in the end, want 44 different data-frames created:
1) dataGL_FLIin 
2) dataGL_FBEout
3) Etc. ...

ADDED: 2 STATION 2 DIRECTIONS EXAMPLE OF MY PROBLEM

```
'The one data frame I have'
Date<-c("01-01-15 04:00","01-01-15 04:20","01-01-15 04:40")
FLIin<-c(96,39,72)
FLIout<-c(173,147,103)
FBEin<-c(96,116,166)
FBEout<-c(32,53,120)
dataGL_all<-data.frame(Date, FLIin, FLIout, FBEin, FBEout)

'The four data frames I would like'
GL_antal<-c(96,39,72)
Station<-("FLI")
Dir<-("IN")
dataGL_FLIin<-data.frame(Date, Station, Dir, GL_antal)

GL_antal<-c(173,147,103)
Station<-("FLI")
Dir<-("OUT")
dataGL_FLIout<-data.frame(Date, Station, Dir, GL_antal)

GL_antal<-c(96,116,166)
Station<-("FBE")
Dir<-("IN")
dataGL_FBEin<-data.frame(Date, Station, Dir, GL_antal)

GL_antal<-c(32,53,120)
Station<-("FBE")
Dir<-("OUT")
dataGL_FBEout<-data.frame(Date, Station, Dir, GL_antal)
```

Thanks, 
lars

Comment: Can't you just use a function and pass the variables for train stations and directions?

Comment: Hey, Christian, thx for your reply. Yes, what you suggest is probably the solution, but I can't work out the correct syntax ...

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? At least the original data and how the final result should look like?

Comment: Thanks to you too, Christian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your example, it is now clearer what you want and I give it a second try. I use `dataGL_all` as defined in your question and the define

```
stations <- rep(c("FLI","FBE"),each=2)
directions <- rep(c("in","out"),times=length(stations)/2)
```

You could also extract the stations and directions from your data frame. Using your example, the following would work

```
stations <- substr(names(dataGL_all)[-1],1,3)
directions <- substr(names(dataGL_all)[-1],4,6)
```

Then, I define the function that will work on the data:

```
dataGLfun <- function(station,direction) {
    name <- paste0(station,direction)
    dataGL <- dataGL_all[,c("Date", name)]
    names(dataGL)[names(dataGL)==name] <- 'GL_Antal'
    dataGL$DIR<-direction
    dataGL$STATION<-station
    dataGL
}
```

And now I apply this function to all stations with both directions:

```
dataGL <- mapply(dataGLfun,stations,directions,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
names(dataGL) <- paste0(stations,directions)
```

Now, you can get the data frames for each combination of station and direction. For instance, the two examples in your question, you get with `dataGL$FLIin` and `dataGL$FBEout`. The reason that there is a `$` instead of a `_` is that I did not actually create a separate variable for each data frame. Instead, I created a list, where each element of the list is one of the data frames. This has the advantage that it will be easier to do something to all the data frames later. With your solution, you would have to type all the various variable names, but if the data frames are in a list, you can work with them using functions like `lapply`.

If you prefer to have many different variables, you could do the following

```
for (i in seq_along(stations)) {
    assign(paste0("dataGL_",stations[i],directions[i]), dataGLfun(stations[i],directions[i]))
}
```

However, in my opinion, this is not how you should solve this problem in R.

Comment: Your code looks brilliant, thx, however it doesn't produce what I hoped it would. Pls see my 2 station 2 directions example added in my question above, thanks again, Stibu

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. I hope that I understood your intentions correctly now. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Stibu, that is brilliant. You definitely solved my problem and reduced my main program from hundreds of lines to just a few. Thanks again. I'll now see if I can "concatenate" (rbind) the 4 list members dataGL$FLIin, dataGL$FLIout, dataGL$FBEin and dataGL$FBEout to just one list or data frame and then export it to a csv.-file (write.csv), so I can use it in Excel to make a pivot table. I'll give it a go but might ask for help again if I fail :)

Comment: You can combine the data frames as follows: `dataGL_combined<-do.call(rbind,dataGL)`.

Comment: Thanks for all your kind help!